# one Fragment to another Fragment on Button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have learned how to change the fragment activity from one to another (all are fragment activities) on button click but now I am having issue with multiple button on same fragment. only first button id works. I have more than one button and each button has different fragment activity. need help

```
package com.test.fragmentation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class List extends Fragment {


    public List() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);


        Button ID = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnHello);
        ID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    HelloFragment NAME = new HelloFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, NAME);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                }
            });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the fragment name with that in which want to move

```
Button ID = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnHello);
            ID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        HelloFragment NAME = new HelloFragment();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, NAME);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    }
                });
```

Change Fragment name on that button click:-

```
ABC NAME = new ABC ();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button ID = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnHello);
            ID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                       FragmentName Name = new FragmentName ();//Name of fragment where you want to go. 

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= 

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, Name);              

fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
notification = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.notification);

```
    notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fr.replace(R.id.container(this is the main activity container layout),new NotificationFragment(this is the fragment you want to go)());
            fr.commit();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```